# How to update values from an asset in hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

**model**

```
asset Route identified by route_id {
  o String route_id
  o String rider_id
  o String parcel_id
}
transaction assignParcelToRider {
  o String rider_id
  o String parcel_id
}
```

**logic.js**

```
var assetRegistry;
var id = assignValue.rider_id;
return getAssetRegistry('org.rytle.Route').then(function(ar) {
    assetRegistry = ar;
    return assetRegistry.get(id);
}).then(function(asset) {
    asset.parcel_id = assignValue.parcel_id;
    return assetRegistry.update(asset);
});
```

Here I want to find the rider_id and update parcel_id there. But here its not finding the rider_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is you need to get the asset, by the asset identifier when using `.get()` and `rider_id` is not that, in your model.

Also - may need more info - but it all rests on `id` getting a value from `assignValue.rider_id` and I can't tell how that was defined / asserted and whether it is within scope. I can see that `id` however, should be in scope for your function below - but using the correct identifier for an asset, this should work (as an example):

```
return getAssetRegistry('org.rytle.Route').then(function(ar) {
      return ar.get(route_id)   // or whatever you've assigned it to or txnobject.route.getIdentifier());   // ie you must get the asset by identifier
      }).then(function(asset) {
           asset.parcel_id = id;   
           return ar.update(asset);
       });
```

and so on;

ps you can check out [sample-networks](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/tree/master/packages) for some examples (eg under 'test' directory) - note these now use `async / await` functions (instead of 'promises' shown above) which came in with Node 8 (and is far easier to write than using promises FYI)